# System Manager run command on windows e2 using eventbridge scheduler

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, powershell, amazon-ec2, aws-ssm

I am running a `Get-process` command on windows ec2 instance using AWS Run Command's `Aws-RunPowershellScript` document and it works successfully.

But when I am using a **aws event bridge scheduler** for the same I am getting the following error:

```
failed to run commands: fork/exec /usr/bin/pwsh: no such file or directory
```

It seems when Run command is invoked from scheduler it's trying to run it assuming linux instance and not windows but not sure why.

Comment: We have a combination of linux and windows instances running. I copied an instance id in hurry and was assuming it to be windows when it was linux. Not closing this question cause it maybe a basic mistake but I think others can learn from it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Incorrectly assumed instance to be windows when it was a linux instance.